# How do I make my launch images for iPhone use the user's status bar?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I tried removing the status bar from my `Default.png` images, but under iOS 6 apps seemingly load with that blue-tinted bar, and since my app uses a black one it doesn't work.

For example, the Facebook app on cold launch has a launch image which uses the user's status bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app will not use the status bar from the launch image. In fact, for the iPad launch image, you have to crop out the status bar. For the iPhone launch images, XCode automatically crops them for you.

Set the tint of the status bar during launch in your project summary settings.

[image]